# Heap corruption detected after normal block c++. динамические массивы

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++, динамические-массивы, обработка-ошибок

Итак, цель программы - создать два динамических массива, сравнить их между собой и наибольший элемент массива записать в новый третий массив, если массивы разной размерности то оставшиеся элементы наибольшего массива записать в третий массив.
Запускаем консоль, вводим размеры массива, записываем значения в новый массив. Вроде как бы все записалось, но
1)не те значения
2)вылезает ошибка
скриншот полагает
[image: Вылезает ошибка, так же значения не совпадают]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int L1, L2, L3, n = 0, k=0, c = 0;
    cout << "Введите длину первого массив" << endl;
    cin >> L1;
    int* array1 = new int[L1];
    cout << "Введите значение массива" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < L1; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = rand() % 50;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < L1; i++)
    {
        cout << "&array1[" << i << "] = " << &array1[i] << " = " << array1[i] << endl;

    }
    cout << "Введите длину массив" << endl;
    cin >> L2;
    int* array2 = new int[L2];
    cout << "Введите значение второго массива" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < L2; i++)
    {
        array2[i] = rand() % 50;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < L2; i++)
    {
        cout << "&array2[" << i << "] = " << &array2[i] << " = " << array2[i] << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < L1 || i < L2; i++)
    {
        if (array1[i] > k)
        {
            k = array1[i];
        }
        if (array2[i] > k)
        {
            k = array2[i];
        }
    }

    if (L1 > L2)
    {
        n = L1 - L2;
        c = L1;
    }
    if (L2 > L1)
    {
        n = L2 - L1;
        c = L1;
    }
    L3 = n;
    cout << "Результирующий массив" << endl;
    int* array3 = new int[L3];
    array3[0] = k;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (L1 > L2)
        {
            L3++;
            array3[1 + i] = array1[c - i];
        }
        if (L2 > L1)
        {
            L3++;
            array3[1 + i] = array2[c - i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < L3; i++)
    {
        cout << "&array3[" << i << "] = " << &array3[i] << " = " << array3[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Разница между длинами массивов: " << n << endl;          // Разница между длинами массива
    cout << "Наибольшее число в двух массивах: " << k << endl;       // Наибольшее число в двух массивах
    cout << "Длина большего массива: " << c << endl;                // Длина большего массива
    delete[] array1;
    delete[] array2;
    delete[] array3;
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрим на это:

```
for (int i = 0; i < L1 || i < L2; i++)
```

Т.е. `i` может выйти за пределы меньшего массива! Скажем, `L1 = 10`, `L2 = 30`, `i = 20` - и условие выполнено, и выход за пределы массива произошел!

Уже UB. Тут у вас явно требуется `&&`...

Дальше у вас в двух разных условиях - `L1 < L2` и `L1 > L2` (кстати, а что будет, если они равны? :)) - выполняется одинаковое присваивание `c = L1`. Терзают смутные сомнения, что вы хотели иного...

Словом, пока исправьте эти ошибки, а там посмотрим.
Только вот при исправлении учтите, что `k` как максимальный элемент, у вас ищется неверно в любом случае...

Comment: Ошибки не исправило

Comment: Ну ведь я же не знаю, *как* вы исправили :) Как я намекнул, в любом случае вашу программу надо переписывать. Кстати, условие задачи у вас тоже поставлено так, что не очень понятно, что надо - ну вот, например:  "наибольший элемент массива записать в новый третий массив" - элемент какого именно массива? Первого, второго? Записать только его? Что значит "сравнить массивы" - по длине, по сумме элементов, сравнить наибольшие значения, etc etc? Какой вопрос - такой и ответ...